# UIDocumentPickerViewController - How to set the navigation bar color

Tags: ios, swift, uidocumentpickervc

I want to set the navigation bar background color of my DocumentPicker to be the same as the rest of my application.

```swift
    let filePicker = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: ["public.content"], in: .import)
    filePicker.delegate = self
    filePicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = self.theme.navigationBarColor

    self.present(filePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

doesn't work.

Other things I've tried:

Use `UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = self.theme.navigationBarColor` - doesn't work and looks too much like a workaround instead of a proper way if it works.

Edit:
Right now our app is redesigned to use the primary color as navigation bar text color, and have the same background color as the DocumentPicker. Answers will still be appreciated.

Comment: Prior to iOS 11, you could do UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor.black and it worked fine. This seems to be a bug in iOS 11. I'm in a predicament where the nav bar is white, and the nav bar buttons (like "Cancel") are white, so they are invisible.

Comment: @JohnnyC I'm having this issue as well.

Comment: [UINavigationBar appearance].tintColor = [UIColor yourColor]; // for button title color 

and [UINavigationBar appearance].backgroundColor = [UIColor yourColor]; // for background color. Worked for me like a charm. I have this issue only iOS 14 version.

Answer (score 3):

This will change the color of the text like "Cancel".

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.blue], for: .normal)
```

and this will change the arrow back color.

```
UIButton.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.blue
```

Don't forget to set it back to your original colors after closing the picker if it required.