# UIDocumentPickerViewController navigation bar buttons color

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11

My app is using red navigation (2) bar with white buttons and texts. When I use system contact picker (3) the status bar is red. When I use documents picker (1) `UIDocumentPickerViewController` then navigation bar is white. How I can change color of navigation bar or text?

When I use code bellow, it works but it change my navigation bar too.

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = .red
```

thanks for help

code:

```
func open() {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .green
        let documentsController = UIDocumentPickerViewController(documentTypes: makeDocumentTypesList(), in: .import)
        documentsController.delegate = self
        viewControllerProvider.getViewController().present(documentsController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

[image: navigation bar]

Comment: use `UINavigationBar.appearance().bartintColor = .green`

Comment: show some additional code

Comment: When I set barTintColor it changes color of root view controller. No effect at document picker.

Comment: try with inside the completion once

Comment: I added UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .green to completion and It makes no effect.

Comment: is this possible to attach the project I will check

Comment: Sorry that is not possible.

Comment: I made sample project https://github.com/raptorxcz/UIDocumentPickerViewController-buttons-color

Comment: give the time i will check

Comment: @KryštofMatěj Did you solve? Thanks

Comment: According to Apple it is a bug. I asked them for workaround. When I get the response I will add it here.

Comment: @KryštofMatěj thanks. Have you a link where Apple states thats it's their bug?

Comment: @KryštofMatěj Have you got response from apple or have you found some workaround for this issue?

Comment: Hi, Apple marked my bug as a duplicate of 33902607. Workaround is below https://stackoverflow.com/a/49926235/3992815

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You can just reset the appearance for `UIDocumentPickerViewController` only by putting this code somewhere in your `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` function and the bar buttons will return to their original blue or you can set any other color of your choice. The bar color, on the other hand is not customizable.

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = nil
}
```

Comment: is this only for iOS 11.0 and above?

Comment: This is the solution for me, i have set tint color to white and in the UIDocumentBrowserViewController couldnt see the `cancel` button. now i have set it to blue. `UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
        
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            UINavigationBar.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UIDocumentBrowserViewController.self]).tintColor = UIColor.blue
        }`

Comment: Hi, I found your answer to work fine as you described with UIDocumentBrowserViewController but I can't get it to work with UIImagePickerController - do you have any ideas here?

Answer (score 4):

Use `setTitleTextAttributes`

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes([NSForegroundColorAttributeName:UIColor.white], for: .normal)
```

[see my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46316961/uidocumentpickerviewcontroller-how-to-set-the-navigation-bar-color/48053025#48053025)

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution I found:

```
    UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = ... some color
    _viewController?.present(documentPicker, animated: true)
```

To my knowledge it is not possible to set the **bar color** only the **tint color** (text color). To keep the tint color for the rest of your project I reset it in the viewWillAppear of the underlying view controller.

Answer (score -2):

as you ask "change color of navigation bar or text?" 
i haven't a solution for change navigation bar it always return nil

```
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true,completion: {

                if documentPicker.navigationController?.navigationBar != nil{
                    documentPicker.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .red
                }
            })
```

but if you agree to change only text

this works for me

```
self.present(documentPicker, animated: true,completion: {

                documentPicker.view.tintColor = .red
            })
```

i understand that it couldn't be the optimal but none of solutions i try work for me